# Can not INSERT INTO Postgresql

Tags: python, linux, postgresql, ubuntu

[simplechan](https://github.com/blobmon/simplechan)
In other words, I installed a message board named simplechan, but I can not log in to a site dedicated to the administrator. Because you need a password to get there. I do not know the password.

I entered in psql as follows

```
simplech_db=# select * from moderator_list;
username | password_md5 | session_id | expire_ts | actions_per_hour
----------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------------
(0 rows)
```

In "simplechan/sql/create_table_query.sql" it was drawn as follows.

> -- tables for moderator things

create extension if not exists "uuid-ossp";  -- this is only required for unique session_id.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS moderator_list (
    username text PRIMARY KEY,
    password_md5 text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    session_id uuid UNIQUE,
    expire_ts timestamp with time zone,
    actions_per_hour int NOT NULL DEFAULT 10
);
```

And I tried it like this, but it was useless. I accessed "IP / mod_login" and entered my password, but I could not put it in.

```
INSERT INTO moderator_list (username,md5_password) values ('my username','mypassword');
INSERT  01
```

When "password" is set to "md 5 _ password", I properly INSERTed it. I accessed "IP / mod_login" and entered the password, but the password is incorrect. It was displayed.
I confirmed it with "select * from moderator_list;" but it came in properly.

```
simplech_db=# select * from moderator_list;  
 username | password_md5 | session_id | expire_ts | actions_per_hour
----------+--------------+------------+-----------+------------------
 myuser     | mypassword     |            |           |               10
```

(1 row)

Comment: You use  **password** in the `INSERT` the columns name is **password_md5**

Comment: So is this about the INSERT failing? Then please provide the error message. If it’s about some third party software not working for you? Then this isn’t the place to ask since it’s not programming, rather using software. It should be addressed to the makers of the software or *possibly* a sister site.

Comment: That INSERT command should have failed, with an error message that `password` is not a recognized column.  (As @RaymondNijland pointed out, that table contains a `password_md5` column, not a `password` column.)

Comment: I added the case when md 5 _ password was added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `INSERT`ing the raw password you want to use, md5 hash it, and `INSERT` the result.

Find the hash of your desired password from the unix command line:

```
echo -n 'mypassword' | md5sum
```

Since the md5 hash of `mypassword` is `34819d7beeabb9260a5c854bc85b3e44`, from psql command line enter:

```
INSERT INTO moderator_list (username,password_md5) VALUES ('my username','34819d7beeabb9260a5c854bc85b3e44');
```

Then log in with a password of `mypassword`

To delete that username and password combination, from the psql command line enter:

```
DELETE FROM moderator_list WHERE username='my username' AND password_md5='34819d7beeabb9260a5c854bc85b3e44';
```

Comment: I did INSERT with that hash, but it was useless. Similarly, it is displayed that the password is incorrect.

Comment: I got it! ! I could do it when I restarted! ! Thank you! ! However, since I want to have a different password, please tell me how to hash the original password with md5! ! Also, please tell me how to delete the user and password_md5 that have already been INSERTed! !

Comment: Great news! I updated my answer with more information, please give it a try.

Comment: Oh! ! Thank you! ! After that, please tell me how to hash the original password I would like to enter! !

Comment: It's in my updated answer above: `echo -n 'mypassword' | md5sum`. Change the quoted string to whatever you want to be your password. Since this is run in a Unix shell, some metacharacters may need further special handling.

Comment: Thank you! ! I was able to do it on the day. Finally, it is one question, but according to my research, I heard that md5 is not so good for security. What is more secure encryption than md 5? And how can I set it?

Comment: That probably merits an entirely new question, but here's a decent answer that might be useful: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31871/140613